# VBS to Open an Excel Workbook Not Displaying

Tags: excel, vbscript

I am trying to run a small VBS script to open an Excel workbook, but every time I run my script, Excel will only load as a background application (confirmed in Task Manager) but will not display. I feel like I am missing something very silly, but I have browsed form after form talking about VBS scripts launching Excel, and I can't seem to get any of them to work. Any input you might have would be greatly appreciated, thanks :)

```
Option Explicit
Dim xlApp, xlBook
Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
xlApp.DisplayAlerts = False
Set xlBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("FilePath", 0, True)
Application.Caption = "OnMax"
```

*Note I replaced the actual file path with just Filepath to make sure it fit and one line and no one had to scroll, but incase it matters the file path is: 
 M:\Projects\Onmax II\Documents\R&D\Standalone App\VB Script Test\Test.xlsm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The script is doing exactly what you asked it to do it started an instance of Excel.
You just didn't tell it yet to make the application visible.

Adding the following code should help

```
xlApp.Visible = true
```